# How to access break points in two application in the same solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging

I have two web applications in the same solution. I put break points in both of them and when debug I can't access but the start up one. How to debug both of them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just right click on your project solution in visual studio then go to properties and in Common Properties > Startup Project select Multiple startup projects. Then choose the appropriate action.

That way you will be able to debug both

Answer (score 1):

You can have only one *active* project at time of compilation/running. By the way, if one active project somehow calls something from another, just press F11 and you will jump into another project and symbols for it will be loaded automatically and you can debug it.

**EDIT**

If you are asking about debugging 2 projects contemporary in parallel, it's not possible with in one VS. If these are the separate projects that communicate with eash others, let's say chat application, you can naturally, by running two instances of VS and debug communication between them.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to open two versions of visual studio, run both solutions, but set the start up project differently for each, and run them both.  The two instances of visual studio should catch the break points of their respective start up programs.  I know this works for windows/console applications.  Although I've never tried it with 2 web applications. You may have to configure the applications to use different ports.